# Going crazy over this python socket problem

Tags: sockets, tcp, tcpclient, sendmessage, tcpserver

## I've been trying to implement a server in python and a client in C that communicate to eachother.

The client accepts N txt files from command line and creates a thread for each file, every thread sets a connection to the server in which it sends all the lines from the file. The python server creates a thread for each connection received. Every thread of the server simply receives the lines but the whole server has to keep track of all the lines received from all the connections. Here comes the problem, when i try to send back to the client the number of lines the server has received, the number is inconsistent and changes every time i execute it.

**CLIENT**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE   // permette di usare estensioni GNU
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>   // funzioni per stringhe
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

// host e port a cui connettersi
#define HOST "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 5050
#define Max_sequence_length 2048

pthread_mutex_t lock;

//funzioni readn e writen per leggere o scrivere nel socket
size_t readn(int fd, void *ptr, size_t n) {  
   size_t   nleft;
   ssize_t  nread;
 
   nleft = n;
   while (nleft > 0) {
     if((nread = read(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
        if (nleft == n) return -1; /* error, return -1 */
        else break; /* error, return amount read so far */
     } else if (nread == 0) break; /* EOF */
     nleft -= nread;
     ptr   += nread;
   }
   return(n - nleft); /* return >= 0 */
}
size_t writen(int fd, void *ptr, size_t n) {  
   size_t   nleft;
   ssize_t  nwritten;
 
   nleft = n;
   while (nleft > 0) {
     if((nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
        if (nleft == n) return -1; /* error, return -1 */
        else break; /* error, return amount written so far */
     } else if (nwritten == 0) break; 
     nleft -= nwritten;
     ptr   += nwritten;
   }
   return(n - nleft); /* return >= 0 */
}

//variabili atomiche che vengono incrementate o decrementate durante la geestione dei thread
atomic_int totale_seq = 0;
atomic_int nthreads = 0;

void *gestionefile(char* nomefile){

    FILE *f = fopen(nomefile , "r");
     if(f == NULL){
        printf("Errore nell'apertura del file %s \n, codice errore dsfasdfa :%d", nomefile, errno);
        exit(1);
    }

    //creo il socket
    int inet_socket;
    inet_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(inet_socket < 0){
        perror("Errore nella creazione del socket");
        exit(1);
    };

    //specifico l'indirizzo e la porta del socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);

    //mi connetto al socket 
    int stato_connessione = connect(inet_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    if(stato_connessione == -1){
        perror("C'\u00e8 stato un errore nella connessione con il socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[CONNESSO] Connessione effettuata con il socket di indirizzo %d \n" , server_address.sin_port);

    //mando il carattere "B" che specifica il tipo di connessione
    char buffer[2];
    char* word = "B";
    strcpy(buffer, word);
    writen(inet_socket, &buffer, 1);
   
    //leggo le linee del file
    char* linea = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
        while(getline(&linea , &size, f) != -1){

        //controllo che la linea non superi la lunghezza massima
        assert(strlen(linea) <= Max_sequence_length);

        // mandiamo la lunghezza della prossima linea
        short dim = strlen(linea);
        short tmp = htons(dim);
        writen(inet_socket, &tmp, 2);

        //mandiamo la linea al server
        char buffer2[dim];
        strcpy(buffer2 , linea);
        writen(inet_socket, &buffer2, dim);
        
        totale_seq++;
        }

    fclose(f);
    free(linea);

    //il thread ha finito di mandare tutte le linee del file
    printf("Il client2 ha finito di mandare le linee del file : %s \n", nomefile);

    //invio sequenza di lunghezza = 0 come intero per terminare l'invio delle sequenze
    short len_0 = 0;
    short zero = htons(len_0);
    writen(inet_socket, &zero , 2);
    
    //se sono l'ultimo thread aspetto che il server mi mandi le sequenze ricevute nella sessione
    if(nthreads == 1){  
        int tmp1;   
        readn(inet_socket, &tmp1, 4);
        int s_ricevute = ntohl(tmp1);
        printf("il server mi ha inviato %d linee ricevute\n" , tmp1);
        printf("io ne ho inviate %d",totale_seq);
        assert(s_ricevute == totale_seq);
    }
    
    nthreads--;
    
    close(inet_socket);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if(argc == 1){
        perror("Errore: client1 deve ricevere almeno un file da linea di comando");
        exit(1);
    }

    //creo tanti thread quanti sono i file passati da linea di comando
    //ogni thread crea una connessione di tipo B e invia tutto il file al server
    pthread_t id[argc - 1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < argc - 1 ; i++){
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, gestionefile, argv[i+1] );
        nthreads++;
    }

    for(int i= 0; i < argc -1 ; i++){
    pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
    }

    printf("Ho inviato un totale di %d linee",totale_seq);
    return 0;
}
```

****SERVER****

```
import socket, sys, struct, threading, math

Max_sequence_length = 2048
PORT = 5050
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
ADDR = (HOST , PORT)
seq_tot = 0

lock = threading.Lock()

def recv_all(conn,n):
  chunks = b''
  bytes_recd = 0
  while bytes_recd < n:
    chunk = conn.recv(min(n - bytes_recd, 1024))
    if len(chunk) == 0:
      raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
    chunks += chunk
    bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
  return chunks
 
def gestisci_client(conn,addr):
  with conn:
    print(f"Nuova connessione da {addr}")
    #devo ricevere il tipo di comunicazione
    tipo = recv_all(conn,1).decode()
    if(tipo == "A"):
      print("connessione di tipo A")
    elif(tipo == "B"):
        gestione_b(conn)
 
def gestione_b(conn):
  n_sequenze_b = 0
  global seq_tot
  
  while(1):
      #devo ricevere la dimensione della linea  
      data = recv_all(conn,2)
      lunghezza = struct.unpack('!h',data)[0]
  
      if(lunghezza == 0 ):
      
        lock.acquire()
        seq_tot = seq_tot + n_sequenze_b
        lock.release()
        
        if(threading.active_count() == 2):
          
            print(f"\n ULTIMO THREAD , DEVO INVIARE {seq_tot}\n")
           
            #se sono l'ultimo thread b e ricevo lunghezza 0, il client 2 ha finito di mandare tutte le linee di tutti i file, quindi mando al client il n di sequenze
            lock.acquire()
            conn.sendall(struct.pack("!i",seq_tot))
            seq_tot = 0
            lock.release()
            
        break
      
      #ricevo la linea e incremento di 1 il numero di sequenze totali ricevute
      data = recv_all(conn,lunghezza).decode()
      n_sequenze_b = n_sequenze_b + 1
      


#creo il socket "server"
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server : 
  #collego il socket all'indirizzo
  try:
      print("[WAITING] : il server \u00e8 in attesa di connessioni")
      server.bind(ADDR)
      server.listen()
      while True:
          conn, addr = server.accept()    
          thread = threading.Thread(target = gestisci_client , args = (conn, addr)) 
          thread.start()
              
  except KeyboardInterrupt: #quando ricevo un'interruzione chiudo il server
    pass

  print("[SHUTDOWN DEL SERVER]")
  server.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The server has no way of knowing, and hence makes a false assumption sometimes, how many connections belong together. E. g. one connection thread may have done its reception before a second connection is established, so the server thinks it was the last file and sends only the count for that one.

> how could i make sure i am sending the count only if there are no connections left?

To make sure, you'd have to inform the server somehow that *there are no connections left* (presumed that you only want to account for one running client at a time). One way is by means of another *tipo di connessione*, which you foresightedly already made provisions for and which the client would send after all sending threads were joined. If the server then got this other connection type, it would send the count over that, after having waited for the previous threads to finish, e. g. with

```
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            if thread not in [threading.main_thread(), threading.current_thread()]:
                thread.join()
```

Comment: Thank you, and how could i make sure i am sending the count only if there are no connections left?

Comment: Do you only want to account for one running client at a time?